# Is there a way to enforce my Lan Settings without launching Internet Explorer?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, proxy

Here is my problem: I am changing the Local Area Network Settings using a .reg file that I found on the web. The specific settings can be found in: "Internet Options - Connections (tab) - Lan Settings (button)" (screenshot of the options that I change with the reg file below). You can open the Internet Options dialog if you search for "Internet Options" in the Start Menu or directly from Internet Explorer: "Tools - Internet Options".

[image: Internet Options - Connections - Lan Settings]

The problem is that every time that I am making a change using the .reg file, I need to launch Internet Explorer before the new settings are applied. Is there a way to avoid this step?

What I'm basically asking: is there a way to make Windows understand that the specific settings have changed without launching Internet Explorer?